# Python Import Different Libraries from Different Versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pydantic

I'm trying to develop a Python script, and I seem to be running into a conflict between two of the libraries that I want to include.

The first dependency that I have is pymoos (https://github.com/msis/python-moos), which is necessary to connect to my communication architecture. I've built the code and manually installed the resultant pymoos.so in the following places:

- /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymoos.so
- /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/pymoos.so
- /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/pymoos.so
- /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/pymoos.so

However, only python2.7 will allow me to 'import pymoos' from the interpreter. Attempting from either of the Python3 versions produces this:

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jun 11 2019, 15:15:01) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymoos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_pymoos)
```

The second dependency is pydantic, which I have only managed to install using pip3, apparently meaning that it's only available from either of the versions of Python3 that I have installed. Attempting to import from Python2 gives the following:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pydantic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pydantic
```

Since I know where the pymoos.so library is, I think that my easiest path forward is to put that in the right place so it works with python3, but I can't seem to find the right place!

Comment: Moos says it supports python 3 so try to install it using pip3. Pydantic definitely only works with python >=3.6.

Comment: That's an interesting idea - I know that pymoos isn't on the pip repositories, so I'm looking into how I can use pip3 to install from the source that I downloaded off github, which generates a shared object library using cmake. Do you have any tips on how to do that? I've been pretty heavily invested in C++ for the past few years so I'm a little rusty on Python configuration and package installation. Thanks again!

Comment: it should be as simple as `pip install path/to/pymoos/code`, but you might be better off using a more widely used database library like asyncpg or psycopg.

Comment: Thank you for the help - you sent me down exactly the right rabbit trail. I wasn't able to just simply install with pip quite that easily, but I was able to use the included setup.py to generate a wheel file and then install that with pip. The two relevant commands were:
`sudo python3.7 setup.py bdist_wheel` and
`sudo pip3 install dist/pymoos-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl`

It worked on one computer just fine, I'm having a new problem with the other where it tells me that this and other .whl files "is not a supported wheel on this platform." So I'm tracking that down.

Comment: @SColvin: I'd like to give you credit for the solution. Is there a way to do that with a comment, or could you please post as a solution so that I can approve? Thanks!

Comment: I've copied my suggestion to an answer (albeit not perfect), you can upvote that and mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my comment:

it should be as simple as `pip install path/to/pymoos/code`, but you might be better off using a more widely used database library like asyncpg or psycopg.

Regarding having to use `sudo`, you might consider using `virtualenv` or similar to setup a dedicated python environment for your application.